# Access files on the user's PC

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is it possible to access files on the user's computer for use on a website.

For example, if the website notifies the user when a message is received with a 'ping' sound.

Can the user change his account settings to use a 'boing' sound stored on his computer, without the need to upload it to the website?

Comment: Why don't you just host different "ping" sounds on the website, from which your user can choose in their profile settings/options?

Comment: If you have a new question, then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Don't edit an existing question into a completely different and unrelated one that makes the answer(s) you already have look like nonsense.

Comment: Possibly you had a question closed which you then reasked and were told to edit the closed question. You should not have been told to edit an unrelated question.

Comment: If people can upvote the answers, surely the question itself must merit being upvoted, because one cannot exist without the other!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking: No. Browsers block access to `file:` scheme URLs from `http:` and `https:` URLs.

If the file is small enough, you could allow the user to select it with a [file input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) then [convert it to a `data:` scheme URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) and then store that in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).